# Changing the security policy for a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

A unit test I've written is failing with the following error message.

`This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.`

The link recommends you enable the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy if you want to . I've modified my Unit test config as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
     <appSettings>
       <add key="TestValue" value="true" />
     </appSettings>
   <runtime>
     <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
 </configuration>`
```

But I still receive the error message. I have a test above it to ensure the config file is being read (it tests `TestValue` is true). The other possibility to fix this is to change the .NET version the project is using to 2.0 rather than 4.0 but Visual Studio says

`You cannot change the specified .NET framework version or profile for a test project`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit tests are run by C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\QtAgent32.exe so adding the flag to QtAgent32.exe.config fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2017 and i've modified the following file to get rid of the problem:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\testhost.exe.config